# Add instagram as an identity provider in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to add instagram as an identity provider, but I'm running into an issue where Azure AD B2C is not able to recognize the id of the instagram user in the JSON response. After calling instagram's self endpoint, this is the response that I get:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "4835453534",
    "username": "myUsername",
    "profile_picture": "https://profilepic.jpg",
    "full_name": "",
    "bio": "",
    "website": "",
    "is_business": false,
    "counts": {
        "media": 0,
        "follows": 10,
        "followed_by": 100
    }
},
"meta": {
    "code": 200
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you notice, the response from instagram is not typical. The data about the user is nested inside the "data" object. In order to extract the values, you need to use claims transformations.

This is what the technical profile will end up looking like -

```
  <ClaimsProvider>
<Domain>instagram.com</Domain>
<DisplayName>instagram</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="Instagram-OAUTH">
    <DisplayName>Instagram</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="ProviderName">instagram</Item>
      <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize</Item>
      <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token</Item>
      <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self</Item>
      <Item Key="scope">basic</Item>
      <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
      <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
      <Item Key="client_id">YOUR CLIENT ID HERE</Item>
      <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
      <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_InstagramSecret" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="instagramData" PartnerClaimType="data"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="instagram.com" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ExtractIDFromResponse" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
```

In this technical profile, you will notice the "ExtractIDFromResponse" transformation. This needs to be added, and should look like this:

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="ExtractIDFromResponse" TransformationMethod="GetClaimFromJson">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="instagramData" TransformationClaimType="inputJson" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="claimToExtract" DataType="string" Value="id" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" TransformationClaimType="extractedClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

You will also need to create a claim type for data, as following:

```
  <ClaimType Id="instagramData">
    <DisplayName>data</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <AdminHelpText>data object from Instagram</AdminHelpText>
    <UserHelpText>data object from Instagram</UserHelpText>
  </ClaimType
```

So essentially, the steps that happen are:

1. B2C gets the JSON response from Instagram
2. B2C maps the "data" object in the response to "instagramData"
3. A claim transformation is run, that extracts out the "id" from the input (instagramData), and saves that into the socialIdpUserId claim.

In order to save the other variables, like full_name, another claimsTransformation needs to be added accordingly